# Processing shows there's no class named AudioClip

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to use SoundCipher library in Processing to make some music pieces,

however, when I run the example of library, some of them showed

"can't find a class or type named AudioClip"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EPtP.png)

Do I miss some important package or library to import?

here's the example code provided by library creator.

```
import arb.soundcipher.*;
SoundCipher sc = new SoundCipher(this);
SCScore score;
AudioClip ac;

void setup() {
  score = new SCScore();
  ac = sc.loadAudioClip("plink.aif");
  score.addCallbackListener(this);  
  score.tempo(100);

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    score.addCallback(i / 4.0, 3);
  }
  score.play();
}

// Parse the callback message triggered during score playback.
public void handleCallbacks(int callbackID) {
 if(callbackID == 3) {
    sc.playAudioClip(ac);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these are best answered by checking out the reference for the library you're asking about. The reference for SoundCipher can be found [here](http://explodingart.com/soundcipher/reference.html).

Looking at that, you'll notice that the `AudioClip` class is in the `java.applet` package. So you'll have to import it as well:

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
```

Comment: thank you so much! I've checked and also searched similar questions on internet, however there's no answer I want , so that's why I post this question here :P